# In what way I should export my Blender file to display on web properly? (lighting effect is not being applied)

Tags: blender, lighting, 3d-modelling

I'm trying to display my Blender GLB file on my website, but the lighting effect isn't applied when it's exported as shown in the screenshot below. How could I solve this?

[image]

Left image: lighting applied.
Right image: lighting not applied.

Answer (score 0):

To use Blender 3D files in website with mouse controls.
**But you have to use your html file in live Server**

Please Visit:
[How to Insert 3D Objects into a Webpage using HTML and CSS](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-insert-3d-objects-into-a-webpage-using-html-and-css/)